# Update column with leading zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Hope someone can help.  I am trying to pad a zero infront of any result that has under 10 digits in column GPF4.
The column GPF4 is designed to be Numeric(18,0) as later on I will be converting this number into Hexidecimal with reversed pairs.
result comes with no changes

here is the code to try and pad the zero infront

```
UPDATE Filter_All
SET GPF4 = RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), REPLICATE('0', 10 - LEN(GPF4)) + CONVERT(varchar(10), GPF4)) + CONVERT(varchar(10), GPF4), 10)
WHERE LEN(GPF4) < 10
```

- actual number 821295578 in GPF4
- expected result 0821295578
- Resulted with 821295578  (no changes)

I tired again, this time sucessfull howerever the result was padded with the last digit from the of the affected row in GPF4

```
UPDATE Filter_All
SET GPF4 = RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), REPLICATE('0', 10 - LEN(GPF4)) + CONVERT(varchar(10), GPF4)) + CONVERT(varchar(10), GPF4), 10)
WHERE LEN(GPF4) < 10
```

- actual number 821295578 in GPF4
- expected result 0821295578
- Resulted with 8821295578

here is the code to try and pad the zero infront

```
UPDATE Filter_All
SET GPF4 = RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), REPLICATE('0', 10 - LEN(GPF4)) + CONVERT(varchar(10), GPF4)) + CONVERT(varchar(10), GPF4), 10)
WHERE LEN(GPF4) < 10
```

- actual number 821295578 in GPF4
- expected result 0821295578
- Resulted with 821295578  (no changes)

I tired again, this time sucessfull howerever the result was padded with the last digit from the of the affected row in GPF4

```
UPDATE Filter_All
SET GPF4 = RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), REPLICATE('0', 10 - LEN(GPF4)) + CONVERT(varchar(10), GPF4)) + CONVERT(varchar(10), GPF4), 10)
WHERE LEN(GPF4) < 10
```

- actual number 821295578 in GPF4
- expected result 0821295578
- Resulted with 8821295578

Comment: Numbers don't have leading zeros. That's maths, not a SQL quirk. The actual value is a binary value, not a sequence of digits.  If you want to display the data with leading zeros, format it on the client or using eg FORMAT : `select FORMAT(GPF4, 'd10') as padWithZeros`.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: `as later on I will be converting this number into Hexidecimal with reversed pairs.` in that case you made things harder. `numeric` is a floating point number. If you use `SELECT cast (@some_num as varbinary(max))` you'll see that the actual bytes look nothing like the digits you entered

Comment: This has [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) written all over it.

Comment: Please attach your table definition. Note that numbers (floats, ints, decimals etc) cannot be padded with zeroes, because 5 is same as 000005

Answer (score 0):

To zero-pad, you'll have to use a string datatype. Using the STR function with a size is a fast way to make a numeric type into a right-justified string. Then you can use the `replace` function to change spaces to zeroes, which gives you the zero padding.

If, however, your number is larger than 10 digits, you'll just get *** as a result. So, if you have access to IIF, you can check if the number has fewer than the minimum characters before trying to zero pad it.

Here's an example with a numeric(18,0) datatype converted to a zero-padded string based off a parameter for the minimum number of characters in the string:

```
declare @t table (
   GPF4 numeric(18,0)
);
insert @t (GPF4)
values (821295578)
     , (1234567890123456)
     , (5)
     , (54321)
declare @MinStringSize int = 10;

select GPF4
     , replace(str(GPF4,10),' ','0') as NearlyRight
     , iif(len(cast(GPF4 as varchar(18)))<@MinStringSize,replace(str(GPF4,@MinStringSize),' ','0'),cast(GPF4 as varchar(18))) as ZeroPaddedString
from @t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replicated the question. And while concatenating, I tried converting both leading 0's and gpf4 into varchar. And it worked.

https://dbfiddle.uk/0TlMaC_s

Please try and let me know if this works.

Answer (score -1):

Try using concatenation as follows:

```
SELECT GPF4
    ,CONCAT(REPLICATE('0',10 - LEN(GPF4)),GPF4)
FROM table_name
--WHERE LEN(GPF4)<10
```

The above example provides an output with GPF4 and padded GPF4

You can try same logic in update statement.

Comment: The question states the column is `Numeric(18,0)`. If you had read the comments you would have seen the problem with this suggestion

Comment: Hi, 
Can you try converting the replicate 0 also and let me know the output in your first query?

like convert(varchar, replicate....)